# ошибка в post запросе

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

```
     submit = (event) => {
    //console.log(this.state);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://uxcandy.com/~shapoval/test-task-backend/create?developer=Agarkova',
      crossDomain: true,
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      processData: false,
      data: {
        username : "User",
        email: this.state.user.email,
        password : this.state.user.password,
        notes : this.state.user.notes,
        task : this.state.user.task,
        file : this.state.user.file
        },
      config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        onUploadProgress : progressEvent => {
          console.log('Upload Progress:' + Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100) + '%')
        }
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
  });
  }
```

не добавляются данные, пишет message: {username: "Поле является обязательным для заполнения", email: "Поле является обязательным для заполнения", text: "Поле является обязательным для заполнения", image: "Не загружено изображение"}
status: "error"
хотя вывожу данные и все это есть в стейте компонента

Comment: 1. код приведен неполностью. 2. бэк точно принимает формдату?

Comment: Базовый url для запросов - https://uxcandy.com/~shapoval/test-task-backend

Ожидаемый MIME-type для POST-запросов - multipart/form-data

Ответ сервера - в формате json. 
Ответ может содержать два поля:

status - текстовая строка - "ok" в случае успешного запроса, "error" в случае ошибки
message - текстовая строка или ассоциативный массив - сообщение с результатами запроса (в случае успешного выполнения), сообщение об ошибке (в случае ошибки), поля может не быть или оно может быть пустым

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию axios передает данные как json. Если вы пытаетесь отправить `multipart/form-data` то следует передавать объект типа FormData

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', "User");
formData.append('email', this.state.user.email);
formData.append('password', this.state.user.password);
formData.append('notes', this.state.user.notes);
formData.append('task', this.state.user.task);
formData.append('file', this.state.user.file);

submit = (event) => {
    //console.log(this.state);
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://uxcandy.com/~shapoval/test-task-backend/create?developer=Agarkova',
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        onUploadProgress : progressEvent => {
            console.log('Upload Progress:' + Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100) + '%')
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
       //handle success
       console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(function (response) {
       //handle error
       console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, но все равно идет ошибка( попробовала посмотреть в консоли обьект, но свойства там только стандартные

Comment: возможно ваш бэкенд настроен только на извлечение json?

Comment: увы( Базовый url для запросов - https://uxcandy.com/~shapoval/test-task-backend
Ожидаемый MIME-type для POST-запросов - multipart/form-data

Comment: а бэкенд на чем?

Comment: бинго на php^^'

Comment: на бэкенде есть возможность точки останова сделать и посмотреть, что приходит в post?

Comment: доступа никакого у меня нет (физического, ssh -nothing)

Comment: никакого доступа и контакта нет, от слова нет вообще (это тестовое задание оно либо сделано либо нет)

Comment: просто вопрос видимо не в js, а в обработке приходящих данных на бэкенде

Comment: я понимаю)) но я не знаю, что я могу сделать в этой ситуации и могу ли я вообще что-то сделать?

Comment: Для начала сделать "тупую" форму для эксперимента, без всякого js с обычными инпутами и попробовать отправить

Comment: в реакте или в хтмл? (я так поняла, что отправить лучше фетчем раз у эксайоса такие беды)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83521/discussion-between-natalia-aga-and-dmitry-kozlov).